# What is the workflow for creating reusable models with rigidbody that can be placed all over the scene

Tags: instances, linked-data, rigidbody

I'm looking for a concept similar to unity engine prefabs. I need to have a library of objects with rigidbody that I can place in the scene. If I change original object properties (material/rigidbody params/geometry), it should apply to all the instances of this object in the scene.

I tried:

- linked objects. Rigidbody properties don't get linked for some
  reason. E.g. if I modify mass on the original, linked instances don't
  update.
- Collection instancing. These kind of instances don't have independent
  simulation and just repeat what was simulated for the original
  collection.

Thank you!